# Finding shortest path between two nodes

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to make a method which finds the shortest way between two nodes, but cant seem to figure it out. I was given two files, one file containing actors (which will be the nodes) and one with movies (which will be the edges).

I have represented a graph as a HashMap where the key is a actor, and the value is a ArrayList with the movies that actor has played in:

```
HashMap<Actor, ArrayList[Movie]> graph;
```

Now i wanna find the shortest way between two actors but i dont know how to. I was thinking DFS or BFS but im not quite sure how to do that with this hashmap..

Comment: If you're having trouble doing this with this HashMap, have you considered using a different data structure?

Comment: Not sure what other data structure to use...

Comment: if you create another map that will contain actors as keys and distance from either of your actors you will be able to find the distance. I know this is not the exact answer you are looking for but it should give you a start. In this [image](https://i.imgur.com/IR2DQir.png), I calculated distance of every node from the node B

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand why you were modeling your graph like this. For basic graph problems, we have 2 ways to model them: **adjacency list** and **adjacency matrix**. In case you want it to be **adjacency list**, it should be `Map<Actor, Set<Actor>> graph;` (I guessed it because you said that movies are edges). And one famous algorithm for finding the shortest path is **dijkstra**. The implementation is a lot on google, you could try to do it.

Comment: I tried making a adjacency list/matrix but the problem for me is adding the edges. I get the graph info from two different files.. File 1 (named actors) contains actorID, actorName, and x amount of movieIDs (all on one line). File 2 (named movies) contains movieID, movieName, rating (all on one line)

Comment: it is supposed to be a graph with marked, parallel and weighted edges. The nodes is the actors and the edges is marked with a movie

Comment: You also need to be able to find out what actors are in a movie. A `Map<Movie, List<Actor>>` would be useful. Or you can flatten that into a `Map<Actor, List<Actor>>` by replacing the movies with their (distinct) actors. A `Set` would be more useful there instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use your current structure (`HashMap<Actor, ArrayList<Movie>>`) as an adjacency list, but there is something missing: an efficient way to go from movies back to actors that starred in them. You can build a `Map<Movie, List<Actor>>`, and that would work... but it is simpler to use a single adjacency list, instead of having one for actors and another for movies. I would do as follows (assuming that `Actor` and `Movie` both have `equals` and `hashcode` implemented, and no actor equals any movie):

```
 Map<Object, List<Object>> edges = new HashMap<>();

 for (Map.Entry<Actor, ArrayList<Movie>> e : graph.entries()) {
     Actor a = e.getKey();         
     edges.put(a, new ArrayList<Object>(e.getValues()));
     for (Movie m : e.getValues()) {
         List<Actor> otherActors = edges.getOrDefault(m, new ArrayList<Object>());
         otherActors.add(a);
         edges.put(m, otherActors);
     }
 }
```

Now you can use `edges` to perform a standard breadth-first search. It is guaranteed to give you a shortest path (there may be multiple equally-short paths) between any 2 actors, and the path will contain the movies that link them.

Comment: i fail to see how single adjacency list will do the job. It should fail when you do `otherActors = getOrDefault` because those two lists contain different types of objects.

Comment: It would fail if edges were not of type `Map<Object, List<Object>>`. Both Actor and Movie are objects.

Comment: A BFS with 2 different adjacency lists would force you to switch from one to the other depending on depth (actorToMovie, then movieToActor, then actorToMovie again). Having  a single adjacency list does away with this hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the entire solution just to point you in the direction, you will have to create a Map<Movie, List> as [tucuxi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69681608/5675692). You traverse every actor one by one and mark the distance on the current actor from your reference actor.

```
private static void fn(HashMap<Actor, List<Movie>> graph, Actor referenceActor) {
    var movieMap = new HashMap<Movie, List<Actor>>();
    graph.forEach((key, value) -> {
        for (var movie : value) {
            movieMap.compute(movie, (k, v) -> {
                if (v == null) {
                    return new ArrayList<>(List.of(key));
                }
                v.add(key);
                return v;
            });
        }
    });


    final var visited = new HashSet<Actor>();
    var dq = new ArrayDeque<Actor>();
    var map = new HashMap<Actor, Integer>();

    dq.add(referenceActor);
    int distance = 0;
    while (!dq.isEmpty()) {
        var size = dq.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var actor = dq.poll();
            visited.add(actor);
            map.putIfAbsent(actor, distance);
            for (Movie movie : graph.get(actor)) {
                // adding every non visited actor in the same movie in the queue
                dq.addAll(movieMap
                        .get(movie)
                        .stream()
                        .filter(x -> !visited.contains(x))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
        }
        distance++;
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

I used `ArrayDeque` here to traverse in BFS fashion you can mend if you want DFS bear in mind the logic to calculate distance will also need to be changed. Pasting the [image from the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDJt2.png), taking node B as reference actor.